# Как сохранить в бд множество одинаковых данных из формы

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Суть проблемы вот в чем. Юзер при регистрации заполняет все данные про себя, а после про своего ребенка. Поля для ребенка - это пол и дата рождения, то есть день, месяц и год. Суть в том, что юзер должен иметь возможность указать столько детей, сколько пожелает. При нажатии на кнопку "Добавить ребенка" - ajax запрос добавляет еще одно поля для ребенка. Вопрос в том, как их сохранить ?! Сначала подумал, что тем же аяксом при нажатии кнопки "добавить ребенка" просто сохранить предыдущего и так далее сколько угодно. Но потом дошло, что юзер то еще не зарегался... И не к кому будет детей привязывать. Может кто нить подкинет идею, как можно поступить в данной ситуации ? Заранее спасибо )

Comment: ну так не делайте запрос просто, сначала юзер заполняет данные, если надо, добавляет ребенка в форму (сделайте кнопку +, по которой будет происходить увеличение формы), а только после заполнения, отправляйте все данные на серврер

Comment: А проблема в чем? Как в базу занести за раз или в сценарии?

Comment: Допустим человек добавил еще 2 ребенка, тогда всего детей 3. У них у всех одинаковые поля "name" и при сохранении их в базу - сохраняются данные последнего ребенка и все)Как тогда быть ?

Comment: Как за раз все данные занести.

Comment: Сделайте базу, чтобы умела хранить дерево. Как раз "родной" формат для родитель-сын. Рекомендую вот эту ссылку http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data?ref=http://habrahabr.ru/post/193166/, там автор рекомендует (где-то с 40 слайда)использовать модель closure tree (2 таблицы): 1-я все уникальные записи, вторая содержит связи между ними.

Comment: Спасибо большое ) Буду пробовать!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создайте таблицу babies(дети) с полями: userbabay (чей ребенок, чьего пользователя), babyname, babylastname, babyinfo в общем сделайте те поля которые требуются для вывода информации.
2. При регистрации, **внимание !** как обычно занесите в переменную `login` значение поля логина ($login = $_POST['login'] и т.д) Теперь он хочет добавить своих детей, с помощью jquery сделайте возможность создания полей то есть нажал на ссылку "Добавить ещё ребенка" то появляется ещё такие же поля для заполнения информации о ребенке, ну или как вариант просто сделайте сразу все поля, допустим 10 полей = 10 детей(первый вариант логичнее) Делайте проверку в PHP: если существуют такие поля с именем или ид: baby1, baby2 и т.д. то заноси в них значения из полей и добавляйте в таблицу users самого пользователя, **НО** самое главное получите ид его, то есть нужно получить ид этого пользователя. Это можно сделать двумя способами функцией `last_insert_id` или же делать запрос, выводя последний ид, последнего пользователя и добавлять к нему +1 (опять же советую первый вариант, без возни) Все теперь у нас есть ид мы все знаем что бы добавить детей будущего пользователя.
3. После запроса на добавления нового юзера делаем запросы на добавления детей, в поле user_baby добавляем id(который мы узнали) этого пользователя, и дальше всю остальную информацию, опять возникает вопрос: А как же ? ведь детей может быть не 1, и ещё нужны запросы. Правильно, если 2 ребенка = 2 запросам на добавления в таблицу babies. Тут можно сделать по разному либо циклом for, либо с обычными проверками на количество детей.
4. Все готово =) Пользователь может добавлять сколько угодно детей.

Чуть-чуть размыто написал, но извините как смог =)

Comment: Уловил мысль ) Про цикл интересная идея, щас попробуем) Спасибо )

Comment: @тигрище, Думаю все получиться :)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так, если бы н ехотел особо заморачиваться.

1. Присваивал юзверю автоинкрементный ID (как идентефикатор).
2. Записывал юзверя и инфу по детям в отдельные таблицы, помечая, "чьи" они идом юзверя.

Comment: Я все так и делал изначально, но проблема именно в том, что бы сохранить данные в бд.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
                 <form method="post" action="/save.php">
                 <input type="text" name="user_name" value=""><br />
                 <!-- прочие поля пользователя-->
                 <input type="text" name="child_name[0]" value="">
                 <input type="text" name="child_birthday[0]" value=""><br />
<!-- далее поля добавляемые , если у пользователя больше детей -->               
                 <input type="text" name="child_name[1]" value="">
                 <input type="text" name="child_birthday[1]" value=""><br />

                 <input type="submit" name="save" value="Сохранить">

                 </form>
  </body>
</html>

<?php // save.php
//подключение е бд и т.д.

$user=array('name'=>$_POST['user_name']);

$db->insert('user',$user);

$user_id=$db->get_insert_id();

$child=array();
for($i=0;count($_POST['child_name'])>$i;$i++ ){
    $child[]=array(
          'child_parent_id' =>$user_id, 
          'child_name' =>$_POST['child_name'][$i], 
          'child_birthday' =>$_POST['child_birthday'][$i], 
        );

}
$db->insert('child',$child);

?>
```

Comment: js для добавления полей не писал, надеюсь с ним проблем не возникнет

Comment: Спасибо большое уважаемый )) Я буквально за пару часов до вашего совета тоже самое смог реализовать ) Этот метод, как я понял самый простой и правильный в данной ситуации!